# What is behaviour when UDPpacket is sent to IP that is claimed by multiple PCs

Tags: udp, ip-address

I know the original problem should be solved to solve real problem(multiple PCs having same IP)
but I wonder if by UDP specification it is specified what happens in case when you send UDP packet to some IP that is used by multiple machines in nw, and all of them are listening on the port that packet is "addressed" to :

-all PCs get packet
-none of them get the packet
-some (0 to n of them) get the packet
-undefined number of PCs get msg, or undefined behavior is possible(aka your OS will format your SSD when this occurs

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is not specific for UDP, but for IP. Unless you have a multicast target the PC tries to find out the MAC-address (e.g. the network card) for the IP by doing in ARP (address resolution protocol) request (broadcast: "Is anybody there having this IP?"). The computer which responds ("I am at MAC ... and I have the IP you ask for") gets put into the ARP table and whenever the system tries to send something to the IP it takes the entry from the ARP table and sends it there (the entries expire after a while).

If you have multiple machines using the same MAC it depends on the OS: some just override an entry in the ARP table if they receive one even if they did not ask for an ARP response (in which case the machine wins which replies last to the ARP request), others save only the first response (in which case the first machine wins) etc. What does not happen is that the data are send to multiple machines.

Answer (score 0):

What you'd want here is send out a UDP multicast stream (server) and have all clients subscribe to it (ip:port).

Comment: problem arises from temporary configuration problem, but I wonder what happens in that small window of time untill things get properly configured... it is basically race condition between some nw stuff and some scripts changing IPs